# Behaviour of the hook mechanism

Tags: lua, hook

I have a strange behaviour with the hook mechanism which i don't understand and id love some help.

It's quite a simple example as i am studying the language :

foo function :

```
 function foo () print ("i'm in foo") end
```

some data function :

```
 function data () print ("This is the data : ") end
```

Then i do the hook set up :

```
debug.sethook(data , "c")
```

And the wired thing is when i call foo this is the output i get :

```
This is the data : 
This is the data : 
This is the data : 
This is the data : 
i'm in foo
```

This is the entire program, so no hidden stuff that could cause it.

I was wondering why is the hook being called 4 times and not just once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the program below, I see only 3 messages, not 4. The explanation is that the call hook is called for each call after it is set: `foo`, `print`, `tostring`, which is called by `print`.

```
function foo () print ("i'm in foo") end
function data () print ("This is the data : ",debug.traceback()) end
debug.sethook(data , "c")
foo()
```